# Toggle Switch Not working in all rows in Django

Tags: python, django

I am intending to implement activating and deactivating a user by changing the value of **is_active** in the database which is a boolean to True or false depending on the the status of the Toggle switch.I have implemented this but the problem is that the toggle switch only works in on raw only the rest doesnt work

[looped output from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfFoD.png)

```html
<main class="page-content">
 <div class="path">
<h5>Administration <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> Users <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> All user</h5>
</div>
{% for message in messages %}
{% if 'success' in message.tags %}
<script>
swal("Success", "{{ message }}", "success");
</script>
{% elif 'error' in message.tags %}
<script>
swal("Error!", "{{ message }}", "error");
</script>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<hr/>
<div class="container-fluid pl-0 pr-2">
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Role</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% if all_users %}
{% for user in all_users %}
<tr>
<td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
<td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
<td>{{ user.email }}</td>
<td>{{ user.role }}</td>
<td>{% if user.is_active %}
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle" style="color:green"></i>
    {% else %}
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle" style="color: red;"></i>
    {% endif %}
</td>
<td><a href="{% url 'admin:edit_user' user.id %}" ><i class="fas fa-edit" style="color:limegreen ;"></i></a>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="is_active"  data-toggle="toggle" id="statuschange" data-on="Activate" checked data-off="Deactivate" data-size="xs"  data-onstyle="success"
 data-offstyle="danger"  {% if  user.is_active %}  {% else %} checked {% endif %}></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</main>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// send request to change the is_private state on customSwitches toggle
$("#statuschange").on("change", function() {
$.ajax({
url: "{% url 'admin:deactivate_user' %}",
data: {
csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
//is_active: this.checked // true if checked else false
},
type: "POST",
dataType : "json",
})
// $.ajax().done(), $.ajax().fail(), $ajax().always() are upto you. Add/change accordingly
.done(function(data) {
console.log(data);
// show some message according to the response. 
// For eg. A message box showing that the status has been changed
})
.always(function() {
console.log('[Done]');
})
})
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //inialize datatable
    $('#myTable').DataTable(   
    );
    //hide alert
    $(document).on('click', '.close', function(){
    $('.alert').hide();
    })
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Why is it only working in one row only the other rows the toggle switch dont work